# Как решают проблему отпадающих websocket в условиях мобильной связи?

Tags: websocket, мобильная-разработка, backend

Проблема связки websocket и мобильной связи:

- В реальной мобильной связи у клиента на ходу меняются IP, пропадает связь и т.п. а значит соединения рвутся по таймауту
- Т.к. websocket это keep-alive соединение - таймаут очень большой и понять сразу после отправки: дошел пакет или нет невозможно.

это приводит к:

- Websocket при отправке сообщения никак не гарантирует доставку получателю: отпало соединение и сервер не знает дошло сообщение клиенту или нет
- Со стороны клиента ситуация естественно аналогична

Как это решают опытные разработчики со стороны кода? Есть ли варианты кроме таймаутов и добавления L7 ответов на уровне WebSocket?

**UPD** Вопрос именно про решения не на уровне L7 путем добавления пакетов в websocket, а на уровнях ниже которые это решать должны (L4)

Comment: Вы не поверите наверное, но эта проблема касается всех сокет соединений в интернете, и решение везде и всегда было и есть - добавление "Keep-Alive" пакетов.(это касаемо разрыва связи, смена IP = обрыв связи)

Comment: А теперь критика выводов: Ваши выводы не верны, и клиент(и сервер) вполне себе узнает что сокет соединение разорвано при попытке отправить данные. возможно с задержкой, но узнает, если конечно он изьявляет желание узнавать такое.

Comment: Совсем не так. Вопрос величин Keep-Alive timeout. только после него можно получить четкий ответ "соединения больше нет".

Во всех tcp-соединениях в интернете таких проблем обычно нет, т.к. по умолчанию величина таймаутов для TCP очень мала и ответ вы получаете сразу. Вы же часто видели ошибку "tls handshake failed" при потере одного пакета - почти моментально.
Websocket живет не по умолчанию и имеет эти проблемы именно от этого

Comment: "Keep Alive" пакет - это то о чем вы говорили сообщая о L7 запросах. И да, просто чтобы небыло мифов - обычное TCP соединение может иметь таймаут в несколько часов, и такое досих пор встречается, и без собственного "Keep Alive"(поверх TCP) - вы не узнаете что соединение потеряно пока не пройдет этот таймаут(до нескольких часов). Так что в этом плане WebSocket ничем не отличается от обычного нативного сокета. И вот ключевое(цитата) :  в интернете таких проблем **обычно нет**.
И еще, при потере одного пакета - протокол TCP попытается его отправить повторно.

Comment: "ничем не отличается от обычного нативного сокета" - так я даже написал чем он отличается. Поведением на уровне L4 достигнутом путем установки величин.

Повторная отправка вообще не решает проблему на мобильной сети. 5 повторов могут просто не дойти, ip-адрес может сменится и т.п.

Мой вопрос задан больше не о том чего я не понимаю (я то как раз отлично понимаю и сеть, и проблематику именно websocket), а о том кто как решает эту проблему если её вообще решают

Comment: Вам уже написали как решают - маленький таймаут и keep-alive пакеты - в вебсокетах есть пинги, если ответ на пинг не пришёл в течение например минуты - считаем соединение разорванным. Когда клиент переподключится, он может сообщить серверу, какое последнее сообщение он получал, а сервер может повторить все сообщения после этого последнего

Comment: Ну и банальные уведомления о доставке никто не отменял - пока клиент не сообщит, что он получил сообщение, считаем его недоставленным, а после переподключения отправляем всё недоставленное повторно (в редких случаях клиент может получить дубликаты сообщений, но их нетрудно отфильтровать)

Comment: Ну т.е. по сути решают путем добавления в L7 логики гарантирующую доставку. И вариант кроме таймаутов и добавления L7 ответов на уровне WebSocket других не практикуется?

Comment: @Mikhail Konyukhov тут https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets всё хорошо расписано - PING / PONG.

Comment: @Mikhail Konyukhov stackoverflow.com как-то описывал свою работу с ws - у них коннекты ws висят год и больше, но скорее всего - они просто не проверяют. Если нормальные браузеры при закрытии вкладки с ws отправляют сообщение о закрытии ws-коннекта, то яблочники это игнорируют и приходится "пинговать" . Есть опыт когда из клиента , постоянно передающего маленькие пакеты, вынимался шнурок на 10 сек, потом вставлялся, не было пропусков пакетов, была задержка но 10 сек, которая потом компенсировалась.